How to cast concrete type to generic (manual specialization)
I'm writing some code and I would like to wrap common functionalities in one place. So here's the code
pub struct Foo { }

pub fn process_foo() -> Result<Foo, X>;
pub fn process_usize() -> Result<usize, X>;

Now I could keep those functions separate and deal with it, but I find it a bit ugly. So I wanted to wrap them around in a generic:
pub fn process<T>() -> Result<T, X>;

Of course Rust doesn't support specialization yet (at least on stable channel) and so I cannot really specialize this method. But I don't have many types, so I came up with the following workaround:
pub enum TypeInfo {
    Usize,
    Foo,
}

pub trait WithTypeInfo {
    fn type_info() -> TypeInfo;
}

impl WithTypeInfo for Foo {
    fn type_info() -> TypeInfo { TypeInfo::Foo }
}

impl WithTypeInfo for usize {
    fn type_info() -> TypeInfo { TypeInfo::Usize }
}

and I've modified my process<T> to allow T: WithTypeInfo only. With this I have:
pub fn process<T: WithTypeInfo>() -> Result<T, X> {
    match T::type_info() {
        TypeInfo::Foo => process_foo(),
        TypeInfo::Usize => process_usize(),
    }
}

This of course doesn't compile, because Rust doesn't know how to convert Result<Foo, X> to Result<T, X> and Result<usize, X> to Result<T, X>. Even though I've guaranteed myself that in both cases these are the same types.
So how to deal with it? Well, the only option I found is through an unsafe macro:
pub fn process<T: WithTypeInfo>() -> Result<T, X> {

    macro_rules! mutate {
        ( $e:expr ) => {
            {
                let item = { $e }?;
                let src = core::ptr::from_ref(&item).cast::<T>();
                let dst = unsafe { core::ptr::read(src) };

                #[allow(forgetting_copy_types, clippy::forget_non_drop)]
                {
                    std::mem::forget(item);
                }

                Ok(dst)
            }
    };

    match T::type_info() {
        TypeInfo::Foo => mutate!(process_foo()),
        TypeInfo::Usize => mutate!(process_usize()),
    }
}

This works. So what this macro does is... pretty much nothing. It takes object and reinterprets it as T. I needed to add std::mem::forget(item); because I ended up with two copies of the same object, one had to be forgotten. And in my real scenario some of those objects have proper Drop implementation.
I've run some tests, and it works.
Is that an ok design? Is there any flaws that I've missed? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Your code is unsound since some type may advertise itself as a TypeInfo::Foo without actually being a Foo and then your read may be undefined. If this code is private or exposed via a sealed trait then it may be fine, but you're still laying down a potential landmine for yourself or other contributors as your code evolves; marking WithTypeInfo as an unsafe trait (and documenting why type_info() must be accurate) would at least flag that landmine.

@kmdreko yes, I am aware of that problem. One of the reasons I don't like it.

For future similar situations where you can't avoid unsafe, your mutate! macro can be replaced with a call to std::mem::transmute. It's no safer than the cast/read/forget dance, but it's designed to cover that use case, and it makes it clearer what it is you're doing.

@user4815162342 I can't check this at the moment, but I think transmute doesn't compile in this case. Because it verifies that sizes are equal, I think? And this is simply not true in this case, because of other variants.

I didn't say this explicitly, but note that Foo and usize are of different size. This affects compilation, because there is only one T, for other variants as well.

You don't need specialization unless you specialize something, obviously. In other words, unless you have a default implementation for all types other than X.
Since you only want to list some types, this is easily supported with normal traits:
pub trait Process: Sized {
    fn process() -> Result<Self, X>;
}

impl Process for Foo {
    fn process() -> Result<Self, X> {
        process_foo()
    }
}

impl Process for usize {
    fn process() -> Result<Self, X> {
        process_usize()
    }
}

pub fn process<T: Process>() -> Result<T, X> {
    T::process()
}

